# LinqPad query does not run in Visual Studio code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, stored-procedures, linqpad

I came across this question on Stack Overflow about different results

[LINQ - Different results with LINQ to SQL vs LINQPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873048/linq-different-results-with-linq-to-sql-vs-linqpad)

I am sort of having a similar problem, but it is with stored procs.

I have some Linq

```
  var op = (from o in Entities.Opportunities
            where (o.OpportunityId == opportunityId)
                          select new 
                          {
                              IsActiveStatus = o.IsActiveStatus,
                              opportunityReasonId = o.OpportunityLostReasonId,
                              comments = o.Comment,
                              competitorId = o.LostToCompetitorId,
                              sourceId = o.DataSourceId,
                              GetCrossSellOptionForOpportunity = Entities.GetCrossSellOptionForOpportunity(o.OpportunityId),
                              projects = Entities.GetOpportunityProjectPaul(o.OpportunityId),
                              items = Entities.GetOpportunityItemPaul(o.OpportunityId),
                              lastUpdated = o.UpdatedDate
                          }).FirstOrDefault();
```

This works in LinqPad, but fails to run within a C# VS2015 environment.

The error relates to the lines in the select statement

```
GetCrossSellOptionForOpportunity = Entities.GetCrossSellOptionForOpportunity(o.OpportunityId),
projects = Entities.GetOpportunityProjectPaul(o.OpportunityId),
items = Entities.GetOpportunityItemPaul(o.OpportunityId),
```

These are either Stored procedures or functions.

As an example:

```
GetCrossSellOptionForOpportunity returns an object of type 
GetOpportunityProjectPaulReturnModel. the context.cs file has the correct 
settings, and GetOpportunityProjectPaulReturnModel is generated as a class 
against the context.tt4 file. The app compiles with no errors, but it still 
crashes
```

Our database is mapped into c# using the EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator addin, located here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator

The physical error returned is:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GetOpportunityProjectPaulReturnModel]
>   GetOpportunityProjectPaul(System.Nullable`1[System.Int64])' method,
>   and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

**Update:**

Please find the image of a screenshot showing that it works it LinqPad.

[image: Please find the image of a screenshot showing that it works it LinqPad.]

**Update 2**

Generated SQL....

```
DECLARE @p0 Int = 1
DECLARE @p1 Int = 7
DECLARE @p2 BigInt = 1798609
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t2].[IsActiveStatus], [t0].[OpportunityLostReasonID] AS [OpportunityReasonId], [t0].[Comment] AS [Comments], [t0].[LostToCompetitorID] AS [CompetitorId], [t0].[DataSourceID] AS [SourceId], [t3].[OpportunityCrossSellOptionID], [t3].[OpportunityID], [t3].[CrossSellOptionID], [t3].[DistanceRank], [t3].[BusinessLineID], [t3].[UpdatedDate], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[GetCrossSellOptionForOpportunity]([t0].[OpportunityID]) AS [t4]
    ) AS [value], [t0].[UpdatedDate] AS [LastUpdated]
FROM [Opportunity] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [OpportunityAssignmentUserPage] AS [t1] ON [t0].[OpportunityID] = [t1].[OpportunityID]
INNER JOIN [OpportunityStatus] AS [t2] ON [t2].[OpportunityStatusID] = [t0].[OpportunityStatusID]
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[GetCrossSellOptionForOpportunity]([t0].[OpportunityID]) AS [t3]
WHERE (([t0].[OpportunityStatusID] = @p0) OR ([t0].[OpportunityStatusID] = @p1)) AND ([t0].[OpportunityID] = @p2)
ORDER BY [t0].[OpportunityID], [t2].[OpportunityStatusID]
```

Comment: In LinqPad are you querying the database or just a test list?

Comment: I am querying against a SQL Server 2016 Db

Comment: The problem is that Entity Framework doesn't know how to translate `GetOpportunityProjectPaul` into SQL so this can't really work, not even in LinqPad. That's why I'm curious as to how it worked there. What was the *exact* code you used in LinqPad?

Comment: @DavidG - it is as above. The article attached talks about the fact that LinqPad uses a different engine.Just did not think it would be that different.

Comment: I don't think that question is relevant here. In LinqPad, what is the generated SQL?

Comment: Also, the LinqPad query doesn't have a reference to `GetOpportunityProjectPaul` so it's not the same at all.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean, does not have a reference?

Comment: The LinqPad query does not call `GetOpportunityProjectPaul`, it's not the same query that you are having problems with in your normal codebase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160296/discussion-between-gilesrpa-and-davidg).

Comment: If you want Linpad to behave identical to VS you have to create a connection to your EF context, not just the (default) connection to the database, which is LINQ-to-SQL. See the options when creating a new connection.